# Is it possible to to know which compiler is used to generate an srec file

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

We have multiple tool chains to compile the code (GNU, ARM).
Is it possible to determine, by inspecting the final output file, which is in "srec" format, which compiler was used to compile the same.

Comment: different compilers do use different mixes of instructions, and some dont use certain instruction flavors at all so it is technically possible to analyze the code, and have a rough idea, but that is not foolproof.  The larger the project along with an assumption of what percentage was compiled (Vs assembled, or mixed compilers) by one compiler.

Comment: The exact same compiler can generate significantly different code depending on compiler options.  Unless a string is put in the image, this can not be done completely.  You must know, what source language was used, is there in-line assembler, etc.  Only a good guess can be made.  As well, two different compilers may output the same binary when invoked with different options. See [decompiler wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/decompiling/info).  Occasionally compilers may use randomness to search for optimal code.  The same compiler can generate different code depending on the day.

Comment: If you have a list of known compilers, and known options, you can generate an "srec" using each and compare.  Or do also not know the source code that was used to generate it?  If you don't know that, you probably don't know the compiler options, unless you never change them in some time window.  People specifically add *revision control*, *compiler*, *build machine* and *time* strings to track this in a binary.  You may also implement commands to print them out.